# How to check if datagridview returns 0 row with specific value

Tags: c#, datagridview

I need something like search datagridview if a row cell has this value(D) and if no row has cell value like this if would do something. this is my code but its wrong

```
ID  Qty  Price   D
==================
1    5    2.00   D
2    4    3.00
3    2    10.00  D
```

thats the example datagridview my code is.

```
 private void noD()
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvPOScart.Rows)
        {
            if (Convert.ToChar(row.Cells[3].Value) != 'D')
            {
                // If no rows withcell[3] having a value of D
                  // (For example only item is with ID 2)
                //Do this

            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Your index is 6? for the example reeplace row.Cells[3].Value

Comment: Yes my actual index for that is 6 bit your right I'll change it to 3 for this example ty

Comment: Just use a boolean flag variable that you set to true if you find a "D" in your column.  *After the loop*, if the flag is false, you have no discount.  If it's true, then you do have discounted items.

Comment: ill try sir and edit the question thank you.

Comment: @LarsTech i manage to make it work sir thank you so much. I edited the answer to my question. is that how you would make it?

Comment: Sure.  But don't put answers in the question.  You can post your own answer and accept it, too.

Comment: @LarsTech done sir. thanks for teaching me so much today

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manage to solve it using this code. as per tip of sir LarsTech and sir CMedina.

```
 private bool withD()
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvPOScart.Rows)
        {
            if (row.Cells[3].Value.ToString().Equals("D"))
            {
                return true;
            }

        }
        return false;

    }
```

and  calling it by

```
 if(withD())
        {
            //code if a row with a cell value of "D" is found
        }
        else
        {
            //code if no cell with a value of "D" is found
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, It's working for me!

```
int allDValuecount = 0;
int allOtherValueCount = 0;
int rowsCount = DataGridViewRow.Rows.Cont;
foreach(DataGridViewRow row in DataGridViewRow.Rows)
{
    if(!row.Cells[3].Value.ToString().Equals("D"))
    {
        allOtherValueCount++;
    }else
    {
        allDValuecount++;
    }
}

if(allDValuecount == rowsCount){//code for all D values}
if(allOtherValueCount == rowsCount){//code for other values}
```

Comment: Thanks sir almost right but there is still a problem. This code activates if it finds 1 row with value not = to "D". What i need is, it will only activate if all rows are not = "D" or if all rows with cell[3] value is = " ".

Comment: still not working sir. i tried converting  the 3 variables to label and variable "allDvaluecount" is always zero and "allothervaluecount" is always = rowcount.